# Efficiently completing multiple transformations in C++

Tags: c++, vector, std

I have to perform the following mathematical operation on every element in an array:

> X = Y*(X - 1) + 1

I currently achieve this as follows:

```
#include <vector> 
#include <algorithm>

for (unsigned i = 0; i < dataSet.size(); i++) {
    std::transform(dataSet[i].begin(), dataSet[i].end(), dataSet[i].begin(),
        std::bind2nd(std::minus<double>(), 1.00));
    std::transform(dataSet[i].begin(), dataSet[i].end(), dataSet[i].begin(),
        std::bind1st(std::multiplies<double>(), scaleFact));
    std::transform(dataSet[i].begin(), dataSet[i].end(), dataSet[i].begin(), 
        std::bind2nd(std::plus<double>(), 1.00));
}
```

Can I complete all three of the operations inside the for loop in a single transform?

Can I complete the operation for every element in the vector of vectors without a for loop?

Comment: Maybe a lambda `transform(..., [](double X) { return scaleFact*(X - 1) + 1;})`

Comment: Have you considered using a GPU?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can I complete all three of the operations inside the for loop in a single transform?

Yes, you can:

```
std::transform(dataSet[i].begin(), dataSet[i].end(), dataSet[i].begin(),
    [scaleFact](double value) { return scaleFact * (value - 1) + 1; });
```

> Can I complete the operation for every element in the vector of vectors without a for loop?

That's a bit tricky, because you can't get around a loop. What you could use is a wrapper around a loop, like [`std::for_each`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/for_each):

```
std::for_each(std::begin(dataSet), std::end(dataSet), [scaleFact](auto& data) {
    std::transform(data.begin(), data.end(), data.begin(),
        [scaleFact](double value) { return scaleFact * (value - 1) + 1; });
});
```

Or even better, a ranged loop:

```
for (auto& data : dataSet)
{
    std::transform(data.begin(), data.end(), data.begin(),
        [scaleFact](double value) { return scaleFact * (value - 1) + 1; });
}
```

Comment: But why would anyone want to use `std::for_each` with a lambda, when you could just use a range for loop.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley Forgot that one :) Thanks

Comment: @Benjamin Lindley sometimes one wants to iterate over only part of a range, not the entire range. `std::for_each` allows for this, a `range based for` loop does not.

Comment: @JesperJuhl: Sure it does, with the trivially implementable `make_range` function.

Comment: @Benjamin Lindley that's not a standard facility - so not something you can assume.

Comment: @JesperJuhl: Not sure why that's a problem. I've never met a programmer who doesn't write their own code.

Answer (score 2):

I'm just gonna put this out there, I know it doesn't technically answer your question. Sometimes I think people overdo it with the algorithms. Is a for loop really so bad?

```
for (auto& data : dataSet) {
    for (auto& e : data) {
        e = scaleFact * (e - 1) + 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: So much this. Why do people try to use all this fancy "tech" just for the sake of it then agonise for days over how to make it "efficient"? The version in this answer is a textbook loop in programming, as simple, readable and quick as can be. No need for anything more than that.